# format php mysql data injson

Tags: php, mysql, json

**My code:**

```
 foreach(array_filter($row) as $key => $value) {
        $output[$value['phone']]['cards'][] = array(
        'email' => $value['email'],
        'mobile' => $value['mobile'],
        'name' => $value['name']
        );}

    echo json_encode($output);
```

---

**Current output:**

```
{
    "919898989898": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "email": "vwxy@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898",
                "name": "abcd"
            },
            {
                "email": "pnqr@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686",
                "name": "abcd"
            }
        ]
    },
    "919923717198": {
        "cards": [
            {
                "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
                "mobile": "8686868686",
                "name": "defg"
            },
            {
                "email": "rstp@test.com",
                "mobile": "919898989898",
                "name": "defg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "phone": [
        {
            "919923717198": {
                "cards": [
                    {
                        "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
                        "mobile": "8686868686",
                        "name": "defg"
                    },
                    {
                        "email": "rstp@test.com",
                        "mobile": "919898989898",
                        "name": "defg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what do you want to get?

Comment: Show the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
foreach(array_filter($row) as $key => $value) {
       $data = [$value['phone']]['cards'][] = array(
        'email' => $value['email'],
        'mobile' => $value['mobile'],
        'name' => $value['name']
        );
        $output['phone'][] = $data;
```

}

```
    echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: I used your code but i am getting below output {
    "phone": {
        "919898989898": {
            "cards": [
                {
                   ...
        },
        "919923717198": {
            "cards": [
                {
                    ...
            ]
        }
    }
}

Comment: @user3395570 i've modified the answer, hope this will help you.